# (Typescript) Setter is not called on a sub-property of a class instance

Tags: javascript, typescript, setter, getter-setter

this is a difficult question that I know is a problem for lots of programs (I will elaborate on this at the end). **I want to create a custom setter in typescript but the datatype of the property being set is not just a number, string, bool it is actually a class object. This works fine - but if a property of the class instance is modified then the setter is not called**. Here is an example of such a situation:

```
//This class contains two properties
class Point
{
    public x : number;
    public y : number;

    constructor(x : number, y : number) { this.x = x; this.y = 0; }
}

//How here is another class that contains a Point
//But it is private and a getter/setter is used
class PointStore
{
    private _foo : Point;

    public get foo() : Point { return this._foo; }

    //Here is the problem, the setter is only called when the whole of foo is changed
    public set foo(n : Point) { this._foo = n; console.log("Foo has been set!"); }

    constructor() { this._foo = new Point(0, 0); }
}

//Use case
let bar : PointStore = new PointStore();

bar.foo = new Point(10, 10); //Logs "Foo has been set!"
bar.foo.x = 20; //Doesn't log anything
```

---

The problem is pretty clear from the example but I just want to say the following:

*Is there anyway around this at all? Because I have seen from APIs such as Unity3D they have opted to make their 'Point' class have only private members and so data can only be set through the constructor* e.g:

```
//the 'Unity' solution
transform.position = new Vector2(10, 10); //Okay
transform.position.x = 20; //Error
```

*But this is not at all a perfect solution to the problem, as it makes programming with the 'Point' class much more difficult from then on.*

If anyone has a trick to solve this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you expecting the setter of `bar.foo` to be invoked when executing `bar.foo.x`?

Comment: I know that won't happen, but how can I make it invoke the setter? @NitzanTomer

Comment: No. A setter is invoked only when assigning a value to the property, but here you're using the getter for the property. Why do you want to do that? What's your objective?

Comment: Well I need some specific code to run whenever any part of the '.foo' is changed @NitzanTomer

Comment: First of all, setter functions don't return anything. You are invoking `bar.foo.x` and expect the setter for `foo` to be invoked?, that does not make any sense in the first place. What you have `bar.foo = new Point(10, 10);` is the correct way to invoke the setter, `bar.foo.x` means "hey JS, navigate the object graph for me so I can access x on a foo"

Comment: Haha @Dummy yea good point and even though I am using a setter in this example - I really want to subscribe to some event that is called whenever any sub-property of 'foo' is changed. Do you know how I could achieve this?

Comment: `Well I need some specific code to run whenever any part of the '.foo' is changed` you can wrap your each `Point` 's property into a setter and a getter, then you can add custom logic to the setter to respond to the property being changed because there is no "onobjectpropertychange" event exists in any language at all as far as I know

Comment: Yea I was thinking about doing that. But in my actual project the point class is used everywhere and there is only one specific circumstance where I want the set to be fired. @Dummy

Comment: Please see my answer

Answer (score 1):

The setter will be used only when you assign a value to the property. One way you can circumvent this is by using `Object.assign`, like so:

```
bar.foo = new Point(10, 10);
bar.foo = Object.assign(bar.foo, {x: 20})
```

You can also go deeper:

```
bar.foo = Object.assign(bar.foo, {x: {z: 20} })
```

Comment: How is that answering the OP question?

Comment: It will allow him to change properties in the class instance, at any level, while also firing the setter.

Comment: The "go deeper" part of the answer is just to demonstrate how it will work for more complex objects, not relevant specifically for the OP's case.

Comment: The OP asked how to know when a value changed, not how to change a value.

Comment: If the setter runs you know the value changed, you mean that you don't know what exactly was changed?

Comment: You obviously haven't understood the OP question. Read it and the comments again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [a Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) for that:

```
class PointStore {
    private _foo: Point;

    constructor() {
        this.createProxy(new Point(0, 0));
    }

    public get foo(): Point { return this._foo; }

    public set foo(point: Point) {
        this.createProxy(point);
        console.log("Foo has been set!");
    }

    private createProxy(point: Point) {
        this._foo = new Proxy(point, {
            set: function (target: Point, property: string, value: any) {
                target[property] = value;
                console.log("Foo has been set (using proxy)!");
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Point%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20public%20x%3A%20number%3B%0A%20%20%20%20public%20y%3A%20number%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(x%3A%20number%2C%20y%3A%20number)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.x%20%3D%20x%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.y%20%3D%20y%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20PointStore%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20private%20_foo%3A%20Point%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.createProxy(new%20Point(0%2C%200))%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20public%20get%20foo()%3A%20Point%20%7B%20return%20this._foo%3B%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20public%20set%20foo(point%3A%20Point)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.createProxy(point)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22Foo%20has%20been%20set!%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20private%20createProxy(point%3A%20Point)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this._foo%20%3D%20new%20Proxy(point%2C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20set%3A%20function%20(target%3A%20Point%2C%20property%3A%20string%2C%20value%3A%20any)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20target%5Bproperty%5D%20%3D%20value%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22Foo%20has%20been%20set%20(using%20proxy)!%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20true%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20bar%20%3A%20PointStore%20%3D%20new%20PointStore()%3B%0A%0Abar.foo%20%3D%20new%20Point(10%2C%2010)%3B%0Abar.foo.x%20%3D%2020%3B))

Comment: Haha, haven't tested it yet but this looks like the answer I was looking for. (Will mark as answer once I read up about it)

Comment: Hmmmm my tsc compiler (I am compiling to ECMA Script 2015 which is supposed to support a 'proxy') is saying "Cannot find name proxy"?

Comment: Right. `Proxy` is a es6 feature, if you're not targeting es6 then it's missing from the definition file.

Comment: Still a good solution, unfortunately I need something that works for es5.

Comment: That only compiles with es5? Because then you can simply copy the `Proxy` parts from the `lib.es6.d.ts` to your own code and that will work.  But if you intend to run it in environments that don't support the `Proxy` then this won't work

Comment: Okay well, I need this for Ludum Dare and thus I am aiming for maximum browser compatibility. Do you have an old browser friendly solution?

Comment: You can use a polyfill in case it's loaded in a browser which lacks it, for example [proxy-polyfill](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/proxy-polyfill)

Comment: I was thinking - could you attach an event to the changing of .x of .y on the Point class? - The problem with this is that it depends on a specific instance of Point (and it shouldn't be static because I don't want every change on a point to call this function)

Comment: Browser used to support [Object.observe()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/observe) but it was dropped: "this API has been deprecated and removed from browsers. You can use the more general Proxy object instead".

Comment: So for the time being, I will use a proxy and change the tsc build target from es5 to es6, but this is temporary. I will look into polyfill. Thanks for all the help :)

Answer (score 0):

The great thing about typescript is that, 2 types are compatible if they have the same shape. So, based on what you described, I think this seems to fit the bill and this will not break your code because `PointStore` here is compatible with `Point` class

```
class PointStore
{
    private x : number; 
    private y : number;

    constructor(x: number,  y: number) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    };

    public get x() { return this.point.x; };

    public set x(x: number ) { 
        // your custom logic here
        this.point.x = x; 
    };

     // setter and getter for other y omitted

}
```

Comment: But this would break compatibility with the rest of my codebase. And I don't want to capture the event from within the point class - it need it from another class lets say 'PointStore' @Dummy

Comment: Then why don't you just do something like my edited answer? Anywhere you need that custom processing when the property is changed, just use that class

Comment: I mean that works, but once again I need to capture the event from within the 'PointWrapper' class.